# Java Array Loop Quits After Shortest Array

Tags: java

I'm trying to get three arrays to run through a loop at the same time.  The arrays are different lengths, and the loop quits after the shortest array is completed.  Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
public class mortgagecalculator4 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        double Loan1[] = {200000, 360, ((5.75 / 12) / 100)};//declares array
        //and defines variables for first loan 
        double Loan2[] = {200000, 180, ((5.50 / 12) / 100)};//declares array 
        //and defines variables for second loan
        double Loan3[] = {200000, 84, ((5.35 / 12) / 100)};//declares array
        //and defines variables for third loan
        double Payment1;//establishes variable for first payment
        double Payment2;//establishes variable for second payment
        double Payment3;//establishes variable for third payment
        double Interest1;//establishes variable for interest for loan 1
        double Interest2;//establishes variable for interest for loan 2
        double Interest3;//establishes variable for interest for loan 3
        double Balance1 = Loan1[0];//declares balance for loan 1
        double Balance2 = Loan2[0];//declares balance for loan 2
        double Balance3 = Loan3[0];//declares balance for loan 3
        double Principal1;// declares variable for principal 1
        double Principal2;// declares variable for principal 2
        double Principal3;// declares variable for principal 3

        Payment1 = (Loan1[0] * (Loan1[2])) / (1 - Math.pow(1 / (1 + Loan1[2]),
                Loan1[1]));//calculates monthly payment for first loan
        Payment2 = (Loan2[0] * (Loan2[2])) / (1 - Math.pow(1 / (1 + Loan2[2]),
                Loan2[1]));//calculates monthly payment for second loan
        Payment3 = (Loan3[0] * (Loan3[2])) / (1 - Math.pow(1 / (1 + Loan3[2]),
                Loan3[1]));//calculates monthly payment for third lona

        System.out.printf("The monthly payments are: Loan One:$%.2f  ",
                Payment1);//prints monthly payment amount for first loan
        System.out.printf("Loan Two:$%.2f  ",
                Payment2);//prints monthly payment amount for second loan
        System.out.printf("Loan Three:$%.2f\n",
                Payment3);//prints monthly payment amount for third loan
        System.out.printf("Each monthly payment breaks down as follows:\n");
        //displays 'each monthly payment...'


        for (int PaymentNumber = 1; PaymentNumber <= Loan1[1]
                && PaymentNumber <= Loan2[1] && PaymentNumber <= Loan3[1];
                PaymentNumber++) {
            //creates 'for' loop that continues until the LoanTerm variable
            //is 0

            Interest1 = Balance1 * Loan1[2];//Determines amt paid toward interest
            Principal1 = Payment1 - Interest1;//Determines amt paid toward principal
            Balance1 = Balance1 - Principal1;//Creates new balance for loop

            PrintStream printf = System.out.printf(" Principal is: $%.2f", Principal1);
            //prints out the amount of principal paid
            System.out.printf(" Interest is: $%.2f", Interest1);
            //prints otu the amount of interest paid
            System.out.printf(" New balance is: $%.2f", Balance1);
            //prints out the new balance amount

            Interest2 = Balance2 * Loan2[2];//Determines amt paid toward interest
            Principal2 = Payment2 - Interest2;//Determines amt paid toward principal
            Balance2 = Balance2 - Principal2;//Creates new balance for loop

            System.out.printf(" Principal is: $%.2f", Principal2);
            //prints out the amount of principal paid
            System.out.printf(" Interest is: $%.2f", Interest2);
            //prints otu the amount of interest paid
            System.out.printf(" New balance is: $%.2f", Balance2);
            //prints out the new balance amount

            Interest3 = Balance3 * Loan3[2];//Determines amt paid toward interest
            Principal3 = Payment3 - Interest3;//Determines amt paid toward principal
            Balance3 = Balance3 - Principal3;//Creates new balance for loop

            System.out.printf(" Principal paid is: $%.2f", Principal3);
            //prints out the amount of principal paid
            System.out.printf(" Interest paid is: $%.2f", Interest3);
            //prints otu the amount of interest paid
            System.out.printf(" New balance is: $%.2f\n", Balance3);
            //prints out the new balance amount

            try {

                Thread.sleep(500);//tells program to sleep for two seconds
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) //catches any exceptions that are thrown
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"? What do you *want* to happen, since they're of different lengths?

Comment: You haven't told us what's wrong. (I'd also strongly recommend that your code should be refactored, particuarly encapsulating the values for a loan, which you've currently got as an array.)

Comment: @Dave: I assume "at the same time" means "in the same loop body".

Comment: @JonSkeet - I was going to suggest an edit on this to improve the code formatting, but I only have link/flag options on this question (no edit/retag.) Is this related to downvotes?

Comment: @robjb: Don't know, to be honest... I have edit/close as options...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
int minLength = Math.min(Math.min(arr1.size(), arr2.size()), arr3.size());
for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
{
   ...
```

?

Comment: I guess the number of iterations not actually the array length but the value of the second array element (i.e. 360, 180 and 84) and the loop stops once `PaymentNumber` reaches 84. - It's quite odd however, that he is iterating over 3 (seemingly unrelated) arrays at once.

Comment: @Thomas: it's written this way, but I assume it's a mistake in the code.

Comment: Well, all 3 arrays are of length 3, so none is shorter. Thus I assume "Shortest Array" is the wrong term here.

Comment: @Thomas: Well, I looked into the description, not into the code. Anyway, different approaches to the answer are more likely to help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok since this is clearly homework I will provide guidance here.  The scenario you are having difficulty with is that you have 3 arrays and need to loop over each of them within the same iteration of the loop.  If that is incorrect please post a comment and I will correct the statements.  So the general problem here is that you have a loop that needs to process X elements within a collection.  The thing to remember here is that we know the number of iterations that must occur, this would be equivalent to the maximum collection length.  So if there are 10 elements in your collection the loop needs to go until 10.

//Some pseudocode
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //10 == largest collection size
{...}

Now the issue here is that you have x-1 collections of smaller size, which prevents you from accessing elements greater than `x sub i`'s size attribute.  So to solve this we need to keep track of the last processed element index.  That being said, the first thing is create a loop that has the following attribute:

for(int i = 0; i < collection.minSize; i++){...}

Record the last index that is processed which will allow you to feed subsequent loops to handle the remaining collections.

Answer (score 0):

Your current loop would stop once `PaymentNumber` is 84, since that's the highest value that satisfies the loop condition (which can be read as `PaymentNumber <= 360 and PaymentNumber <= 180 and PaymentNumber <= 84`, note that `PaymentNumber` must be lower than all of those).

It seems like the three arrays are not related to each other so you might just use 3 different loops for each array or better, write a method that takes a loan (array) as a parameter and which contains the loop:

```
private static double handleLoan(double payment, double initialBalance, double[] loan) {
  double balance = initialBalance;

  for (int paymentNumber = 1; paymentNumber <= loan[1]; paymentNumber ++) {
    interest = balance * loan[2];
    double principal = payment - interest;
    balance = balance - principal;

    System.out.printf(" Principal is: $%.2f", principal);

    System.out.printf(" Interest is: $%.2f", interest );
    System.out.printf(" New balance is: $%.2f", balance );
  }
  return balance;
}
```

Then call it like this (note I use your variables, see side notes at bottom):

```
Balance1  = handleLoan(Payment1, Balance1, Loan1 );
```

A couple of side notes:

1. Variable/parameter names starting with a capital letter are bad practice and against the naming conventions.
2. Refactor your loan arrays to objects, since arrays are not typesafe and might have different lengths (see Jon Skeets comment)